# VS2010 formatting hotkey?

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Is there a hot key to force VS to format the current line/block in C#? (Similar to what happens when you add a semicolon to the end of a line or add a closing brace)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see the shortcuts (they are dependent on your settings) in the Edit/Advanced menu, where you have *Format Document* and *Format Selection*.

Comment: Amazing - so many years and I never even noticed that menu item. D'oh.

Answer (score 2):

Place the cursor on one brace, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>{</kbd>, then <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>F</kbd>.

You can also format the entire document by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>.

Comment: The Ctrl+E chords didn't work for me; probably a result of different keyboard bindings. +1

Answer (score 2):

There are:

<kbd>Ctrl + K + D</kbd> - it formats the *whole* document.

<kbd>Ctrl + K + f</kbd> - it formats the current selection.

These also appear under the `Edit -> Advanced` menu.

See [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/da5kh0wa.aspx) on MSDN, these appear under `Edit.FormatDocument` and `Edit.FormatSelection`.